firebird extraction 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position
I'm trying to extract data from a Firebird database using Python, but I keep encountering the same error no matter what encoding I try.

'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position

def get_conn(self):
    conn_id = self.get_connection(self.firebird_conn_id)

    schema = unquote(conn_id.schema)
    password = unquote(conn_id.password)

    self.connection = fdb.connect(
        host = conn_id.host,
        port = conn_id.port,
        database = schema,
        user = conn_id.login,
        password = password,
        charset = 'ISO8859_1'
    )

    return self.connection

The problem seems to be with the connection, as it occurs when including it. I suspect there is an error before the encoding.

Did you try to set charset = 'UTF8'?

Have you tried with the newer firebird-driver which replaced fdb?
